# Custom Config section in azure functions?

Tags: azure-functions

we are using Recurly's .Net api client, it requires a custom config section like the following. Does azure functions support this?

```
<configsections>
<section name="recurly" type="Recurly.Configuration.Section,Recurly"/>
</configsections>

<recurly apikey="xxxxxx" subdomain="test"/>
```

Comment: Heheh, I just started the same process. "Oh, I'll make a function to report on Recurly stuf"... "Oh".. "I guess not"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, custom config sections are not currently supported in Azure Functions.

Comment: Fabio, are you guys planning to add support for custom config sections in Azure functions?...and if you are is it in the backlog or it's 'just ideas' for now? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are plans to support custom config files. This is still little far, but part of the runtime enhancements to support running functions out of process.

Comment: Please, please add this.  Functions are really, really close to being useful but have to have a way to specify the various configurations.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante: is there support for custom config sections now?

Answer (score 1):

You won't able to keep going configuring your Azure Functions in this way. All configurations are made by appsettings.json or Application Settings Blade o Azure Portal.

But, you're able to find out some interesting configurations 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768490/azure-functions-using-appsettings-json).