# Configuration file in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to read from a JSON configuration file in Azure Function. Is there a way to refer to the file without hard-coding any paths(assuming it's in same directory as the code).

The solution in another answer was something like:

```
string configuration = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationFile) ? "" : File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot\functionname\filename);
```

Is there a better way to get this path, or read JSON configuration in general for Azure Function?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the solution you found is the recommended approach, but with the next release, which is starting to roll out today (5/30/2017), we've introduced a feature to enhance this.

You can learn more about it here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function

Comment: The new runtime has been fully deployed and you can now follow the approach documented in the Wiki. Please let me know if this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

you're able to find out some explanations about this same topic on this another thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768490/azure-functions-using-appsettings-json).

I hope that this information help you.